# LSTM error - 'logits and labels must have the same shape'

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I have searched the other threads on the here regarding the error, but am unable to figure out the issue. I am trying to create an LSTM using a toy dataset with two predictors and three outcomes, setting the output layer to sigmoid such that each outcome label is afford a probability between 0-1. My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#create toy dataset
d = {'custID': [101,101,101,102,102,102,103,103,103],
     'X1': [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
     'X2': [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
     'y1': [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1],
     'y2': [0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],
     'y3':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#seperate preds (X) from outcome (y)
X = data[['custID','X1','X2']]
y = data[['custID','y1','y2','y3']]

X.set_index('custID', inplace=True)
y.set_index('custID', inplace=True)

#reshape
X = X.values.reshape(3,3,2)
print(X)

y = y.values.reshape(3,3,3)
print(y)

#create LSTM
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, input_shape=(3,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(12, return_sequences = False),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(X,y, epochs=10)
```

This yields the error (*ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 3) vs (None, 3, 3))). It works if I set the output layer activation to softmax, but that yields a probability across all 3 labels that sum to 1, instead of a probability for each label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fixing the 'same shape' issue

I think you want to change your model to this

```
#create LSTM
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, input_shape=(3,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(12, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

and if we look at the model summary

```
model.summary()
```

We get the following output

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 3, 6)              18        
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_8 (LSTM)                (None, 3, 12)             912       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 3, 3)              39        
=================================================================
Total params: 969
Trainable params: 969
Non-trainable params: 0
```

We can see that it really looks like the data is flowing in the correct shape

## Showing that this model works

Let's take the above model and train it

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss='binary_crossentropy')
dataSet = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((X,y)).repeat(1000)
model.fit(dataSet, epochs=5)
```

Returns the following training results

```
Epoch 1/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2522
Epoch 2/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0142
Epoch 3/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0048
Epoch 4/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0023
Epoch 5/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0012
```

Looks like it trains up Fantastic!

I think the main issue was the `return_sequence=False`, which basically got rid of your second dimension of data.  The `Flatten` was unnecessary, and if you fixed the return_sequence the Flatten then caused another issue.

Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: Great, thank you. Could you explain what this line is doing: dataSet = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((X,y)).repeat(1000)?

Comment: that line takes the x,y training data and repeats it 1000 times.  Now each epoch really represents going through the data many many times, but it's kinda annoying to see 5000 epochs being displayed in the output, so this just does the same but with only 5 lines.  If this answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer as per the SO standard practices.